# Gitlab job artifact different from the locally ran commands to build the python project

Tags: python, docker, gitlab

I am running a few commands in one of the `gitlab pipeline` stages like below:

```
provisioner_build:
  image: python:3.8-buster
  stage: provisioner_build
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install zip
    - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - cd provisioner
    - pip install . --target=dependencies
    - cd dependencies && zip -r ../snowflake-provisioner.zip . && cd ..
    - cd src && zip -r ../snowflake-provisioner.zip . && cd ..
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - provisioner/snowflake-provisioner.zip
```

I am trying to upgrade a few packages and install the packages from requirements.txt and add the dependencies and the source code to the zip file as shown. IT WORKS FINE when I download this artifact and deploy it in AWS for the lambda function via Terraform. However, when I am trying to create a Makefile and use the same commands and docker image to run the commands, that specific build doesn't work after deploying it on AWS.

Below is my command which I run via `Makefile` on the docker image:

```
    apt-get update && apt-get install zip; \  
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip; \  
    cd provisioner && pip install requirements.txt --target=dependencies && cd dependencies && zip -r ../snowflake-provisioner.zip . && cd ..  && cd src && zip -r ../snowflake-provisioner.zip . && cd .. && cd .. ; \
```

I also compared the structures of the two zips. Everything is the same except for a couple of packages with additional different versions like the below:

gitlab job artifact zip file have:

```
typing_extensions-4.5.0.dist-info
```

Manually built after running commands on docker image have:

```
typing_extensions-4.5.0.dist-info  
typing_extensions-4.6.0.dist-info
```

So, what am I missing here?